# Is there a way to quickly create an IF ISBLANK for multiple areas?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm a college academic advisor, so I'm trying to figure out ways to automate some of the data entry we do.

Right now, I have excel curriculum sheets for all my students that lists what they've taken along with what they need to take, something like this [made up grades and semesters]:

```
ENGL 1101  3 hours  WI87 AT    
ENGL 1102  3 hours    
MATH 1111  3 hours  SP98 A
HIST 1112  3 hours  FA20 FA20     
CORE 2000  1 hours
```

These are separate rows in Excel.

What I would like to do is have a separate excel file for their graduation plan, but I want to pull data from that original curriculum but only if the grade is not a value of A, B, C, D, AT, BT, CT, DT, KT, S, ST and maybe some others.

I've done IF(IFBLANK ...) and had success but only for one row at a time. I figured I'd ask about that, but the TRUE ideal would be it to pull the row only if the grade is not the above mentioned values - and then for that formula to either be easily replicated so I'm not asking advisors to write formula every time because that seems counter-intuitive.

*The true goal is for the graduation plan to pull a list of courses from the student's curriculum sheet that are in progress (which have a semester plugged into the grade field) or not taken (which would then be blank) and ONLY those courses.*

Desired outcome:

```
ENGL 1102  3 hours    
HIST 1112  3 hours  FA20 FA20      
CORE 2000  1 hours
```

I feel like I haven't explained it as well as I could, so I will answer ALL the follow ups that I know how to if I can get some help.

Comment: Can you add a little more data to your sample input and, more importantly, give an example of your desired output for the corresponding input?

Comment: Just use a filter to exclude the blanks and copy/paste visible cells.  Or write a Query or VBA routine that does the same.

Comment: I've added more to the data set and the desired output; I can continue to add if necessary. I've used stackoverflow for basic troubleshooting but never asked a question. The headers, if it matters, are "Course" "Hours" "Semester" and "Grade"; ideally any Grade that's blank or a semester in progress (a la the HIST 1112 that the student is taking Fall 2020) will pull into this other file.